# A method to plot pixels by intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing

**Context**

What my program does is import an image that is binarized and map every white pixel from the image to an x-y plane. I have no issues with that section of the code, but when I tell the program to plot every pixel with an interval of 14, it gives me a plot that is not equally spaced. For instance, if I have a set of x points [x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5....x_n] and y points [y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4 y_5....y_n] and I want to plot pixels within an interval of 2, it would have a list that looks like this: [x_1 x_3 x_5....x_n] and [y_1 y_3 y_5....y_n].

[image: The image that I used]

**Code**

```
import numpy as np 
import tkinter
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from vpython import *
from numpy import loadtxt
import math
from PIL import Image
import os
import cv2
from pylab import plot, ginput, show, axis
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from statistics import mean
im = cv2.imread('/Users/beadpile/Desktop/aman/geeks12.jpg')
blue = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]
# Get X and Y coordinates of all blue pixels
Y, X = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2))
print(max(X))
xpoints = np.array(X)
ypoints = -np.array(Y)
test_list=list(zip(xpoints, ypoints))
points = dict()
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(30) 
f.set_figheight(2)
#To find the max points of white region to plot the edges instead of the whole region
for x,y in test_list:
    if x not in points or points[x]<y:
        points[x]=y
x,y = zip(*points.items())
# I start to define interval here
xdif=[]
ydif=[]
print("len",len(xpoints))
for j in range(0,len(x),14):
    d=x[j]
    xdif.append(d)
for i in range(0,len(x),14):
    e=y[i]
    ydif.append(e)
print(ypoints, xpoints)
plt.plot(xdif, ydif, '*',markersize=6, color='red')
#plt.plot(xx, yy, '*',markersize=2, color='red')
plt.plot(x, y,".", markersize=2,color='blue')
plt.show()
```

**Question**

When you plot the points, it gives you points that are irregularly placed; in some regions, two consecutive pixels are much closer than the interval I defined, and some are much further.
for instance, this is the plot that I get
[image]

The stars are the points within intervals. but it seems like somewhere between 100 and 200, consecutive pixels are much closer and elsewhere they are further. if I picked pixels every 14th place from my list then I should get a plot that resembles it, but that is not the case. for instance if I have a set of points and want to plot every 2nd position of the x axis I should get something like this
[image: hand drawn description of what I expect]
How can I solve this issue and plot the pixels?

Comment: Please provide an input image and corresponding output image, both expected and actual. Then clarify which is which.

Comment: @MarkSetchell ow my bad, I've now added more information to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that the blue pixel coordinates (`X` & `Y`) are equally spaced and sorted along the x-axis first, ultimately resulting in a subsample that is equally spaced along the x-axis. However, `numpy.where` returns the non-zero entries sorted along the y-axis first.

```py
In [5]: a = np.zeros((3, 2), dtype=bool)

In [6]: a[1, 1] = True

In [7]: a[2, 0] = True

In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False]])

In [9]: np.where(a)
Out[9]: (array([1, 2]), array([1, 0]))
```

Since you haven't provided an example image, it is difficult to test a solution. However, the substituting the following line with the corresponding assignment in your code should fix this particular issue (there may be others):

```py
X, Y = np.where(np.all(im==blue,axis=2).T)
```